# Can I execute two commands in one line in batch?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

Yes I know you can do it in cmd with & but something is wrong with this concept and I don't know what...

```
set a=2
set b=5
set /a c=%a%+%b% & set /a d=%a%-%b%
echo c=%c%
echo d=%d%
pause >nul
goto START
```

If I know well, this should work, but as in the picture you can see, It doesn't recognise *set* or work at all...

[my concept](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kjmNT.png)

Comment: `set /a c=a+b,d=a-b`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My comment as an answer:

```bat
Set "a=20"
Set "b=5"
Set /A c=a+b,d=a-b
Echo %%c%%=%c%
Echo %%d%%=%d%
Pause >Nul
GoTo START
```